# How to iterate through list and remove item

Tags: python, json

I made a copy of my releases JSON object because removing items from a list while iterating over it will cause a ValueError, so the copy will have the same JSONObjects as the releases_data, but now when I try to remove the JSONObject from the list copy I get:

***self.releases_data_copy.remove(x)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list***

```
  releases_data = []
  releases_data_copy = []

  #code omitted
  self.releases_data_copy = self.releases_data
  for x in self.releases_data:
        for i in self.games_data:
            if x['game']['id'] == i['id']:
                data = {'releases_object': x, 'games_object': i}
                self.grouped_data['results'].append(data.copy())
                self.releases_data_copy.remove(x)
```

Comment: You're not actually copying the list with that assignment.  Instead, you merely have two references to the same list.  If you want to copy a list, you need to force Python to allocate new storage for it, as in `x = y[:]` for instance.

Comment: Note that if the same `i['id']` occurs more than once in `self.games_data`, then you will try to remove the same `x` more than once from the list.

Comment: Each x object has its own unique id, so I could  just do self.releases_data_copy.remove(x['id']) , correct? And I allocated new storage  self.releases_data_copy = self.releases_data[:], but it still gives me the same error as above, thanks for the reply!

Comment: Probably you'll find you're answer over here.
[Python 2.7 gives ValueError list.remove(x) x not in list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14126786/5313264)

Comment: I'll be sure to check that out, thank you very much guys

Comment: Is there any way the same `x` could occur more than once in `self.releases_data`?

Comment: No every x has its own unique id, with no duplicates, when I find the answer I'll be sure to post it, thanks guys!