# how do i fix this, x not in list

Tags: python, typeerror

this is the code for this sub routine

```
def elimination():
    global name
    global contestants
    global tempContestants
    global lipsync_songs
    global bottom_two
    bottom = tempContestants[0:len(tempContestants)-1]
    tempContestants.remove(bottom)
    bottom1 = tempContestants[0:len(tempContestants)-1]
    tempContestants.remove(bottom1)
    bottom_two = [bottom, bottom1]
    print(bottom_two[0], "and", bottom_two[1], "I'm sorry my dears but you are up for elimination")
    lipsync()
    eliminated = bottom_two[random.randint(0,len(bottom_two)-1)]
    bottom_two.remove(eliminated)
    safe = str(bottom_two)
    print("Ladies, I have made my decision")
    print(safe+", shantay you stay!")
    print(eliminated+", sashay away!")
    contestants.remove(eliminated)
    if eliminated == name:
        print("You have been eliminated!")
        quit()
```

and here is the error message

```
    tempContestants.remove(bottom)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

what does this mean and how do i fix it?

Comment: What is `tempContestants`? What do you want that line to do?

Comment: @MichaelBianconi or just `tempContestants[:-1]` - assuming OP wants a new list holding all but the last contestant.

Comment: Do you want `bottom` to be the final contestant? Then its just `bottom = tempContestants[-1]`.

Comment: As an aside, you don't need all of those `global` statements. `global` is only useful when you are assigning values (variable on the left hand side of the equals sign). When all you are doing is referencing a variable, python figures out whether its local or global when it first compiles the function.

Comment: @tdelaney i'm not sure what you mean by if i bottom to be the final contestant

Comment: You have a variable called `bottom`. What would you like that variable to be? My guess is that you want it to be the final item in the list. You haven't given us enough context. Usually, you want to post a working example of the problem and expected result. The less guessing we have to do the better we can help.

Comment: @tdelaney i'd like bottom to be an item in the list bottom_two. that's really all it's used for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 2.7 throws ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126726/python-2-7-throws-valueerror-list-removex-x-not-in-list)

Comment: @NathanClement sorry but not really

Comment: But you create `bottom_two` from `bottom`. You aren't selecting `bottom` properly. All I'm asking is what you want `bottom` to be.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know what `bottom` should be and what the intent of this program is. But instead of my guessing... tell me!

Comment: bottom is a random item in the list tempContestants

Answer (score 1):

This reproduces your error:

```
In [644]: [1,2,3].remove(4)                                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-644-181ce8c0fac7> in <module>
----> 1 [1,2,3].remove(4)

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
In [645]: [1,2,3].remove(3)
```

Looks like `bottom` is a list of elements of array;

```
In [689]: [1,2,3].remove([1,2])                                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-689-9c95562dca44> in <module>
----> 1 [1,2,3].remove([1,2])

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

===

```
bottom = tempContestants[0:len(tempContestants)-1]
tempContestants.remove(bottom)

In [691]: x = [1,2,3,4]                                                                        
In [692]: bottom = x[0:len(x)-1]                                                               
In [693]: bottom                                                                               
Out[693]: [1, 2, 3]
```

You could remove the items iteratively:

```
In [694]: for i in bottom: x.remove(i)                                                         
In [695]: x                                                                                    
Out[695]: [4]
```

or just select the slice that you want to keep:

```
In [696]: x = [1,2,3,4] 
In [698]: x[-1:]                                                                               
Out[698]: [4]
```

Comment: this doesn't help

Comment: I'm trying to show you that `tempContestants.remove(bottom)` produces this error because `bottom` (what ever its value is) is not in `tempContestants`.  Surely you can figure out why!  Or you can wrap this `remove` in a `try/except` block.

Comment: OK, looks like you want to remove all but the last - then just slice it appropriately.  See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

This code will randomly discard one of the last two contestants. I don't know if this is your intent, but I will throw it out as a straw man.

```
import random

def elimination():
    # get last two contestants
    candidates = tempContestants[-2:]
    if len(candidates) != 2:
        print("Sorry, not enough players")
        quit()
    print("{} and {}, I'm sorry my dears but you are up for elimination".format(
            *candidates))
    lipsync()

    # select and and remove the loser
    eliminated = random.choice(candidates)
    candidates.remove(eliminated)
    safe = candidates[0]
    tempContestants.remove(eliminated)

    # report the news
    print("""Ladies, I have made my decision.
{}, shantay you stay!
{}, sashay away!""".format(safe, eliminated))

    # decide fate of game
    if eliminated == name:
        print("You have been eliminated!")
        quit()

def lipsync(): pass
tempContestants = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
name = "F"
elimination()
```

Running this, you will get two possible outputs because of the random choice. One run results in

```
E and F, I'm sorry my dears but you are up for elimination
Ladies, I have made my decision.
E, shantay you stay!
F, sashay away!
You have been eliminated!
```

Comment: it says can't multiply sequence by no int of type builtin_function_or_method ??

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: thank you i'll try it tomorrow and tell you if it works

Comment: @RyanLaker - I editted to so show my full test code and it works without the error. The problem is in code you haven't shown.